# Change Excel Worksheet Tab Color

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I have added a worksheet to an excel spreadsheet using the following code using the `xlsx` package in R

```
library(xlsx)    
wb <- CreateWorkbook()
newsheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = 'Sheet1')
```

Is there a way to automatically change the color of the tab for "Sheet1"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to tabs in [`xlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf)

My first instinct was to look look at [`XLConnect`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf) but there is no reference to tabs there either.